# Issues with QRC and Resource Display in PySide6 Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt-designer, pyside6

I am currently trying to create a UI for my Python program using PySide6 and custom_widgets. However, I am encountering problems with the QRC. Buttons and other elements are displayed correctly, but my resources (images, icons, etc.) are not appearing properly in the app. When I preview in Qt Designer using "Ctrl+R," everything looks fine, but in Python, the contents are not visible. To better illustrate the problem, here is an example:

I started with an empty project, where I added a label and included my photo under pixmap:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmgwX.png)

To demonstrate that everything else works, I also added a button and converted the whole thing into Python using the following command:

`pyuic6 untitled.ui -o untitled.py`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cPLC.png)

In my UI file, you can also see that the resources are correctly integrated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG5bM.png)

Here is the excerpt from my resources file, where it can be seen that the image is actually included:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC1jn.png)

Here is a screenshot of my UI, where you can see that my resource file is included:

In the next step, I tried converting my QRC to Python using the following command:

`pyside6-rcc -o resources_project.py resources_project.qrc`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7RCM.png)

The conversion into Python works flawlessly, and it is also evident that the whole thing is indeed being converted into PySide6:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usALg.png)

This also works wonderfully. However, when I now execute my code, the result looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAStF.png)

Here is my code:

```
########################################################################
## IMPORTS
########################################################################
import sys
import os
from PySide6 import *
########################################################################
# IMPORT GUI FILE
from untitled import *
########################################################################

########################################################################
# IMPORT Custom widgets
from Custom_Widgets import *
########################################################################


########################################################################
## MAIN WINDOW CLASS
########################################################################
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()


########################################################################
## EXECUTE APP
########################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
########################################################################
## END===>
########################################################################
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong? I'm not getting any error messages or anything, so it's hard for me to analyze why the content is not being displayed.

I have already tried several things, including reinstalling PySide as well as custom-widgets and all their associated components. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Since I'm not receiving any error messages and everything seems to be correct, I'm a bit confused about what else I can do. I would be grateful for any tips or similar experiences.

I have already tried several things, including reinstalling PySide as well as custom-widgets and all their associated components. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Since I'm not receiving any error messages and everything seems to be correct, I'm a bit confused about what else I can do. I would be grateful for any tips or similar experiences.

Comment: Try adding `import resources_project`.

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. Thanks, that was the solution :D

Comment: Note that pyuic is the PyQt tool, but if you're using PySide you can *not* use it (PyQt and PySide are similar in scope and behavior, but shall **never** be used together). In that case, you should use `uic -g python somefile.ui -o somefile.py`. In theory, that should also automatically add the import for the resource file if it's specified in the ui file.